# What is the default value of an uninitialized boolean array, in C?

Tags: c, boolean

I have something like,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main()
{
    int t,answer;
    bool count;
    long long int L;
    scanf("%d",&t);
    while(t>0)
    {
        answer = 0;
        scanf(" %lld",&L);
        bool count[L];
  //  .....restofthecode. NDA Constraint.
```

What would be the default value of all the elements of `arr[x]`?
Is it `false` **always**? Or `true`? Or any random value?

Comment: the default value is whatever garbage was in the assigned memory location when the program started up.

Comment: There's a good reason that a lot of newer languages won't even LET you do things like this.

Comment: Don't tell us you have *something like* that. Show us your actual code.

Comment: Have you defined a type called `boolean`?

Comment: @KeithThompson Added info. Couldn't share more than this.

Comment: I believe your question has now been answered; both existing answers tell you (correctly) that the elements of your `count` array have indeterminate values.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no type named `boolean` in C but there is `_Bool` and in `stdbool.h` a macro `bool` that expands to `_Bool`.

```
#include <stdbool.h>

#define X 42
bool arr[X];
```

`arr` elements have an initial value of `false` (that is `0`) if declared at file scope and indeterminate if declared at block scope.

At block scope, use an initializer to avoid the indeterminate value of the elements:

```
void foo(void)
{
     bool arr[X] = {false};  // initialize all elements to `false`
}
```

**EDIT:**

Now the question is slightly different:

```
long long int x;
scanf("%lld",&x);
bool arr[x];
```

This means `arr` is a variable length array.  VLA can only have block scope, so like any object at block scope it means the array elements have an indeterminate value. You cannot initialize a VLA at declaration time. You can assign a value to the array elements for example with `=` operator or using `memset` function.

Comment: The declaration can't be at file scope (assuming the actual code is reasonably similar to what's in the question).

Comment: The code in your question *will not compile*. Please update your question; copy-and-paste the exact code that you're feeding to the compiler. Don't retype it. If you're using `<stdbool.h>`, then the `#include` directive should also be in the code in the question. We can't possibly guess which errors are in your original code and which were introduced when you summarized or re-typed it.

Comment: The problem in this is, I am using a dynamic value for the array. So I can't do arr[x] = {false}

Comment: @ouah: The code in the question has been changed again.

Comment: @ouah thanks for the updated answer. But the problem is, if I use = operator, I would need a for loop for a long long int, which is taking a lot of time.

Comment: @explorer use `memset(count, 0, sizeof count)` to have all array elements to `false`.

Comment: @explorer: Why do you expect a `for` loop to take a lot of time? Have you measured it? Do you need to initialize the array, or can you write the code that uses it so that it never accesses an element that hasn't been initialized?

Comment: I have time restrictions for the program. Trying to reduce a nested for loop. @KeithThompson

Comment: @explorer: That doesn't answer my question -- but since timing is beyond the scope of you're question, I'll just drop it.

Comment: I need to initialize the array. @KeithThompson

Answer (score 1):

As per your code, in local scope

```
boolean arr[x];
```

itself is invalid. `x` is used uninitialized.

Just FYI, in global [file] scope, all the variables are initialized to `0`. In local scope, they simply contain garbage, unless initialized explicitly.

---

**EDIT:**

[After the edit] All the variables in the `arr` array will have garbage value. It is in local scope [auto].